# Will Samsung support Google's fingerprint API from Marshmallow?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api

Is there any information available on whether Samsung's Marshmallow update will use Google's new fingerprint API or keep to using their custom SDK or both?

I see that they have started rolling updates to beta testers, but these are not available in my country and I cannot find other information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From samsung developer forum, someone did try the android fingerprint api with samsung galaxy s7 edge. and it works!

[link to samsung developer forum](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=289993&startId=zzzzz~)

Answer (score 4):

The S7 [supports both](http://www.androidcentral.com/galaxy-s7-and-s7-edge-support-both-marshmallow-and-samsung-fingerprint-apis) Android M fingerprint API and Samsung's Pass SDK.

S5 and Note4 don't support the Android M API, as indicated in [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764937/fingerprint-api-ishardwaredetected-always-returns-false) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal)..

Not sure about S6

Comment: S6 supports Android M fingerprint API

Comment: How about Samsung Note 5?

Comment: Note 8 doesn't support it too. That is shame.