# FingerPrint API isHardwareDetected always returns false

Tags: android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api

I am using my Samsung S5 G900F(API 23, ANDROID 6.0.1) to test the latest Android Fingerprint API.

I tried to build Google Sample project
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

But I am facing some problems

`mFingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()`

This always returns false. I have double checked on Settings that I have enrolled my fingerprint and I am using Fingerprint to unlock my device.

I had also tried this function

```
mFingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()
```

which also returns false.

Does this mean my Samsung S5 (which got its offical 6.0.1 update) is not supported or I am missing something?

Comment: Did you find any answer regarding this? I am facing the same issue with Samsung Note 4. Thanks.

Comment: Me too, with Samsung S5 G900F

Comment: I guess only few devices are supported for now.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well for Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 6.0.1.

The Native Android SDK API for detecting the Device's Fingerprint reader always returns false:

```
fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()
```

After surfing around looking for solutions it appears that the Galaxy S5 is not compatible with Android's native SDK Api FingerprintManager:
http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=294791&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000030

The solution would appear to be installing the Samsung library for support if you wanted this ability:
[Android M FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() returns false on a Samsung Galaxy S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal)

Answer (score 1):

Even Samsung S5 has fingerprint with 6.0, Samsung didn't implement Android Fingerprint APIs(standards) in this device. Still they are using their own PASS Sdk in this device.

I remember Note 4 also still uses PASS sdk even it has 6.0.