# Android FingerPrint isHardwareDetected not working

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint, galaxy, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have some problems whit the Samsung S5 and Huawei M2.

My Huawei has not API 23 but my S5 has Android 6.0 and fingerPrint.

```
public static boolean checkHaveFingerHardware(Context ctx) {
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Global.API23) {
        AppLogger.w("API < 23");
        return false;
    } else {
        fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) ctx.getSystemService(Service.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
    }
    if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
        AppLogger.w("Not FingerPrint");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mandatory for Android Fingerprint API that the android version is equal or superior to Android 6.

It seems that this is a common problem with multiple Samsung devices such as Galaxy S5 running Android 6+:

[Android M FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() returns false on a Samsung Galaxy S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal)

[FingerPrint API isHardwareDetected always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764937/fingerprint-api-ishardwaredetected-always-returns-false)

The only solution is that you can implement the Samsung Pass Api for those devices:

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass

http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/pass/index.html