# Android FingerPrint API isHardwareDetected returns false for Samsung Note 4

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am trying to implement FingerPrint Scanner in my app.

I followed below tutorial:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial

In Samsung Note 4, FingerPrintManager's isHardwareDetected() is returned as false even though I successfully registered two fingerprints from Settings.

Does anyone of you know what might be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Which Android Version runs on your Note 4? Do you have the permission to use the Fingerprint (AndroidManifest + Runtime)?

Comment: Its running on Android 6.0.1. Yes I have declared the permission in Manifest. I have not added Runtime permission. I will try to add and update you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the Note 4 doesn't support the Fingerprint API (just the Samsung Fingerprint). You should try your code with another device if possible.

Comment: I tried with Samsung s7 edge. Its working fine. So, I wanted to find out the solution for Note 4 as it comes under the same brand. Anyways will check. Thanks

Comment: You are right. I tried with run time permission. Still it gives it as isHardwareDetected as false. :-|

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the implementation of the Fingerprint scanner in some old Samsung phones such as the S5 and the Note 4.

Check this link [Android M FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() returns false on a Samsung Galaxy S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal) to see an example of how you can achieve this using the Samsung pass sdk.

You can also refer to http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/pass/index.html for the documentation of the pass sdk.