# Samsung galaxy note 4 fingerprint not found

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am working on an app where I use fingerprint. Everything seems to be good but when I debug my app,

```
fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()
```

returns false. Why?

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

if(!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()){
    textView.setText("Your Device does not have a Fingerprint Sensor");
}
```

I have read some answers on Stack Vverflow that there is a problem with the Note4 fingerprint - it is an old phone and it does not support the FingerprintManager. Is this the problem? Is there any workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android FingerPrint API isHardwareDetected returns false for Samsung Note 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266406/android-fingerprint-api-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-for-samsung-note-4)

Comment: What is the problem? That post does not contain any answers and any suggestions for workaround. That post does not contain any information that may help to answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note4 don't support Android Fingerprint API.

You have to use Samsung proprietary PASS SDK:
http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass

Comment: Thank you! I did not think to look for this on the samsung web site