# Huawei P9 lite fingerprint support

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, huawei-mobile-services

Do you know if [Huawei P9 lite](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjmnsytzMnSAhUKuxQKHXPUD8kQFghXMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fconsumer.huawei.com%2Fit%2Fmobile-phones%2Fp9lite%2F&usg=AFQjCNHv57elgDHbpBw58eNc6qa63afWNA&bvm=bv.149093890,d.d24) does support Fingerprint?
Is it possible to use [Android 6.0 Fingerprint API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html) or is it supported through some custom proprietary API (Huawei SDK)?

We are evaluating to buy some smartphones and we would like to know how this feature is supported on this specific device.

Comment: I don't think fingerprint is available to customize in android, it's one of those things that remain as it is

Comment: @LucaNicoletti what does that mean? Samsung supports both the scenarios; fingerprint with plain vanilla Android API 6.0 and through proprietary Samsung API (Samsung Pass).

Comment: Samsung pass use Android 6.0 Fingerprint API to register a fingerprint and save in the same account passwords and else

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Not all samsung devices support Android 6.0 Fingerprint API, as reported for sample [in this question (S5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal). [PASS is a Samsung proprietary SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass). I think the meaning of the question is if Huawei P9Lite have some kind of proprietary SDK for fingerprint API like Samsung, or if is his fingerprint scanner are full compliant with Android 6 Fingerprint API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [P9 and P9-lite](http://www.androidauthority.com/huawei-p9-lite-vs-huawei-p9-quick-look-696376/) both **do** support fingerprints.

It seems development for the fingerprint scanner seems to run through the standard Marshmallow API. I'm basing that on:

- No fingerprint hardware [SDKs](http://developer.huawei.com/ict/en/resource/sdk) listed by Huawei
- No fingerprint [API](http://api.huawei.com/apiexplorer/api/classify) listed by Huawei
- [PayPal](https://androidcommunity.com/paypal-brings-full-support-for-androids-fingerprint-api-20160826/) fingerprint support was only announced when Android Marshmallow Fingerprint API launched

Comment: The question is about P9 lite.

Comment: P9 lite still supports fingerprint and will still use the  same api - it would be a waste of resources for huawei to develop a custom api just for their cheapest model

Comment: We tried a P9 with a sample App using Marshmallow 6.0 Fingerprint Api and it worked; we are not sure that P9 Lite will work the same because it's using a different biometric hardware.